# The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) protocol stream is incorrect. The MARS TDS header contained errors

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) protocol stream is incorrect. The MARS TDS header contained errors.

I have an asp.net 4.6.2 web application using EF and Dapper running on two web servers.  We have experienced this error two times where all of the sudden this error appears on many or all queries running on that machine resulting in thousands of errors above until resetting the site fixes it.  The other machine runs fine.   Everything online seems to state it was an issue resolved in a sql server 2008 service pack.  We are running sql 2016.  Has anyone dealt with an issue like this?  Any tips on how to resolve this or find the root issue?

Comment: TDS is a proprietary protocol and is undocumented. As such, all non-Windows 3rd party implementations are bound to throw errors like this every once in a while.

Comment: We're having the same issue. Might be related: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/32752

Answer (score 0):

We had this, in a linq query, I tried to concatenate a return value prefixing a static string and got this very random message.  Got the field straight from the database and changed afterwards, worked a charm.